# Interpolate missing values (NA) in geochemical data with R

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm currently stuck trying to interpolate missing values (NA) with R in my geochemical data.

Up till now I combined data from x-ray fluorescence analysis and magnetic susceptibility derived from the same drill core, so my current data looks like this:

```
   Bohrung.x  Bohrmeter Tiefe Vol..Susc..Meas..in.10..5.SI Vol..Susc..Meas..in.SI
1    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.34                       2.0530             2.0530e-05
2    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.35                       1.8835             1.8835e-05
3    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.36                       2.6866             2.6866e-05
4    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.37                       2.3182             2.3182e-05
5    TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.38                       1.8425             1.8425e-05
6    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.39                       2.2694             2.2694e-05
7    TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.40                       2.0429             2.0429e-05
8    TRE 15A       <NA>  0.41                       1.6823             1.6823e-05
9    TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.42                       1.2559             1.2559e-05
10   TRE 15A       <NA>  0.43                       0.6900             6.9000e-06
11   TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.44                       2.1336             2.1336e-05
12   TRE 15A       <NA>  0.45                       1.5240             1.5240e-05
13   TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.46                       2.0326             2.0326e-05
14   TRE 15A       <NA>  0.47                       2.0245             2.0245e-05
15   TRE 15A 0 - 0,93 m  0.48                       2.6620             2.6620e-05
       Ba     Sn    Cd Pd    Ag Mo     Zr    Sr    Rb   As Se Au Pb  W Zn Cu Ni
1      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5  302.20   0.00  0.00  0  0.00  0 337.85 40.37 26.33 0.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7  405.44 167.71 37.32  0 78.81  0 402.12 36.37 26.14 7.98  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8      NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
9    0.00   0.00  0.00  0  0.00  0 503.24 44.96 31.94 0.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10     NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
11 200.84   0.00  0.00  0  0.00  0 200.09 40.17 27.75 0.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12     NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
13 240.12   0.00  0.00  0  0.00  0 188.05 39.25 30.40 0.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14     NA     NA    NA NA    NA NA     NA    NA    NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
15 149.52   0.00  0.00  0  0.00  0 262.96 42.20 26.38 0.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

(full csv file):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y8bb7nw4k5erkd/TRE15AExpo.csv?dl=0

I tried to use na.approx to replace the NAs in between my measurements.
Therefore I created a zoo series (as seen in many other similar problems) using the depth (called Tiefe in my data frame) as Index.

```
library(zoo)
TRE_Tiefe<- zoo(TRE15A)
index(TRE_Tiefe) <- TRE_Tiefe[,3]
```

So I tried to run na.approx, hoping it would interpolate the missing values for the chemical elements ...

```
TRE_Tiefe_approx <-na.approx(TRE_Tiefe, x= TRE_Tiefe$Tiefe, xout = TRE_Tiefe$Ba, na.rm =  TRUE, maxgap=1)
```

but all I get is ...

```
Error in merge.zoo(object.x, zoo(, xout)) : 
  series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In zoo(, xout) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I'm not sure where my mistakes are located and how to correctly apply na.approx (or any other function if na.approx isn't the right option) to interpolate my missing values. I would really appreciate some help! Thank you in advance for your time :-)

Comment: zoo objects cannot have duplicate times in them and you can't interpolate if there are duplicates in x.  Please put the data right in the post and cut it down to a small set but large enough to illustrate the problem.  Use `aggregate` to combine rows with duplicates.

Comment: In my data shouldn't be any duplicates, I guess using the depth as index isn't the right thing to do and is the reason why the line "cannot merge with non- unique index ..." appears. As for the data file, I tried to present it a smaller version as a table but it didn't really work, I'll try again to edit it into a better table .

Comment: I added a small set of my data as suggested.

Comment: Please show the output of dput(X).  It is too hard to use the data in the form shown.  See the instrucions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page for more info on asking quesitons.